# showing a surface is smooth and computing first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry

let $U \subset R^2$ be a non-empty open set and let $f:U \to R$ be a smooth function. If $Y \subset R^3$ given by

$Y={ (u,f(u,v),u+v) \in R^3|(u,v) \in U}$

show $Y$ is a smooth surface and compute its first fundamental form (FFF).

To show Y is smooth I computed its partial derivates and showed that the cross product partial Y by u and partial Y by v does not equal 0. i.e. partial Y by u = (1, partial f by u, 1) and partial Y by v= (0, partial f by v, 1). Is this a correct computation? Also, I know that showing the cross product of tangent vectors (u and v) not being 0 implies smoothness. I just want to know if taking Y's partials is an accurate way of expressing tangent vectors.

To compute FFF I simply applied the normal method to compute the various dot products of the partials written above. Again, I'm just unsure if my computation of the partials is correct.

Any thoughts would help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your theory is absolutely correct but just to make sure there is no mistake, I recommend you solving the question and I can confirm for you if it's correctly done.

Answer (score 0):

If U is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, we say that a map $\overline{Y}:\mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is
smooth if each of the n components of $\overline{Y}$ have continuous partial derivatives of all orders. From calculus 
we know that $\overline{Y}_{u,v}(u,v)=\overline{Y}_{v,u}(u,v)$ if $\overline{Y}$ is smooth. It should be noted that a 
smooth surface is not necessarily regular.

The first fundamental form is:

$g_{11}=2+(\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u})^2$

$g_{12}=g_{21}=1+ \frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u} \frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}$

$g_{22}=1+(\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v})^2$